# Are questions about representing distorted voices via different typefaces and different languages represented by enclosing brackets welcome here?

Tags: discussion, scope

If I were to ask a question on using separate fonts to represent distorted or alien speech, <or enclose some kind of bracket to represent talking in another language>, how well would that question be received?

Comment: FYI: the `<`-bracket doesn't work in posts, you need to use `&lt;`.

Comment: There's also the ⟨mathematical brackets⟩ – U+27E8, 9.

Comment: There is a precedent- In Terry Pratchett's Discworld series, Death speaks in his own font.  However, I agree that the place to ask this is Writers.SE.

Comment: Piggybacking on cobaltduck's comment, you could also try [the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), which is sort of a combination Sci-Fi/Fantasy Stack Exchange and Writers Stack Exchange :).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang They really don't take kindly to questions either not having a definitive answer or not being directly about strategies to accomplish something using consistent systems.

Comment: I see. Perhaps if you changed the phrasing of your question, then? Or perhaps there's some sort of graphic design SE as this sounds a bit like it could benefit from a visual artist's perspective?

Answer (score 12):

I don't think it's [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, as it doesn't specifically deal with the *English* language.

I don't know the context of your question (it might be good to add it!) but if you're writing a book, you might want to visit our sister sites [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I don't think the worldbuilding section would be right for this question. But the Writing one might be spot on.

Comment: Wholly agree with this answer. Not sure why some disagree that Worldbuilding would not apply. Sounds like the OP is doing some worldbuilding.

Comment: I think that generally in English texts (academic or journalistic, for example)  foreign words or phrases are italicized. This is about how English language usage deals with foreign words. That said, I don't know about "long quotes" but there are precedents for this (to also be in italics).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that kind of question is on-topic here.

I agree with Glorfindel's suggestion to consider [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), since the help center says

> Questions on these topics are welcome here:
>
> - Non-fiction, technical, scholarly, or journalistic writing.
> - Writing fiction, poetry, or song lyrics.
> - General copywriting, **style,** and organization.

Another possibility for questions about typography is the [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange.

However, keep in mind that questions that seem like "[idea generation](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/do-the-on-topic-rules-fit-non-fiction-particularly-technical-writing/1272#1272)" (per the Writers help center) or "Brainstorming or idea gathering" (per the Graphic Design help center) are broadly off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites. So make sure your question is narrow enough in scope to avoid falling into one of these categories. For example, rather than asking "How can I use typography to indicate talking in another language?", which if taken literally could be answered with anyone's opinion, you might ask "What techniques are commonly used in published novels/graphic novels to indicate talking in another language?", which implies that answers should be based primarily on facts rather than on opinion and which narrows the scope to whatever category of literature you're interested in.

Some kinds of questions about [typography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) are on-topic for ELU. The exact lines are probably blurry, but I would say that the main thing that makes a typography question on-topic here is some element of specificity with regard to the English language; it also helps if the question is clearly objective and interesting.